# using cabal with tsocks

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm able to use apt-get with my proxy like:

```
$ sudo tsocks apt-get install ghc
```

But trying to use with cabal:

```
$ sudo tsocks cabal update

Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
Warning: http error: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorClosed
cabal: Network.Browser.request: Error raised ErrorClosed
```

Not sure who to point the finger at here.